# Mounting a CD image as a user under Linux

Tags: linux, iso-image

I want to mount a (.iso) CD-image under Linux (I am using Ubuntu). I know that I can do it with mount using the loopback device, but for that, I need to be root. Is there any way to do it with user privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you probably want is [fuseiso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FuseIso).  You do need to add the account to the fuse group, but after that mounting as any user with fuse privileges is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it myself, as I just use the command line and enter the password, but [this](http://www.acetoneteam.org/) program appears to be the sort of thing you are after

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus ( the Gnome file-manager ) gives you an option mount an iso when right-clicking on the iso.